# Using Metapost for titles in Context

Tags: sectioning, context-mkiv, metafun

I'd like to use Metapost to format my titles like this (not exactly like this, so no need to complain about design issues :)):
[image: format I would like to have]

The problem is that when I try to use the following macro I get an error:

```
tex error       > error on line 4 in file 
/------------/minimal-mpgraph.tex: ! Undefined control sequence

<argument> \setstrut \begstrut \getheadtitle 
                                  \endstrut 
\MPLIBgraphictext ...\startTEXpage [scale=10000]#1
                                                  \stopTEXpage 
l.4 ...\setstrut \begstrut \getheadtitle \endstrut }


1     \starttext
2     \def\MPLIBgraphictext#1{\startTEXpage[scale=10000]#1\stopTEXpage}
3     
4 >>  \MPLIBgraphictext{\setstrut \begstrut \getheadtitle \endstrut }
5     \stoptext
```

I'm guessing here that the problem is internally the \getheadtitle. I'm quite clueless how to solve this though. Is there something wrong with my macro or is it just impossible to pass section titles to macros using Metapost? Any help is appreciated.
Code:

```
\define[1]\DashedText%
    {%
    \startuseMPgraphic{dashed_number}
        graphictext "#1" % the part "#1" does not work :(
            scaled 5
            dashed evenly
            withdrawcolor (0.1,0.4,0.1)
            withfillcolor (0.6,0.8,0.9)
            withpen pencircle scaled 3.0pt
    \stopuseMPgraphic
    \useMPgraphic{dashed_number}{}%
    }

\setuphead [section]
    [
        number=no, 
        textcommand=\DashedText,
    ]

\starttext

\startsection [title={Fancy Title}]
\input knuth
\stopsection

\stoptext
```

Comment: I managed to get this to work by: graphictext "\currentstructuretitle", still have no idea why \getheadtitle is not working...

Comment: Well, seems like I found the proper solution (though not yet quite sure why): deeptextcommand instead of textcommand, and everything works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't what I would call a *definitive* answer, but here's what I found in my investigation.

It does look like using `deeptextcommand` is your best option here.  As seen on the [Context Wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Titles#Formatting_Titles_with_.5Csetuphead), `deeptextcommand` gives you access to the full text of the command without anything else.  When I look at the `-mpgraph.tex` file generated by running `context` using `textcommand`, I see that your macro is passed

```
\setstrut \begstrut \getheadtitle \endstrut
```

as the parameter, and (this is a guess) `\getheadtitle` is undefined outside of a sectioning context since this is in a separate `.tex` file.  Using `deeptextcommand` gives you just the text used in the `\startsection` command, so the `-mpgraph.tex` file sees

```
Fancy Title
```

as its argument.

Here's one thing I noticed while tinkering.  If you want to change the text style of your fancy section heads, I think you'll need to include it in your `MPgraphic`, as `deeptextcommand` is applied before the `style` setup.  Alternatively, you can change the style of individual sections by using

```
\startsection[title={\em Fancy Title}]
```